# Trying to join two datasets, but str() function shows slash marks----

Tags: r, string, join, merge

I have been trying to merge two files, both with the common variables COUNTYCD (a code for counties used by the Department of Labor's Bureau of Labor Statistics. I have converted them into chr variables, and attempt to merge/join them, but to no avail. When I run R's str() function, I get the following:

```

File X:
$ COUNTYCD : chr  "46013" "46013" "46013" "46013" ...

File Y:
$ COUNTYCD : chr  " \"01001\" " " \"01003\" " " \"01005\" " " \"01007\" " ...

```

I note that File Y has slash marks, although both denote chr as the variable type. Any idea what these slash marks mean? I have tried join, merge, and other functions, but they simply won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the additional quotes (as indicated by the escaped `\"` in the `str` output) and leading whitespaces in `COUNTYCD` of File Y.

You can use `gsub` to replace the quotes and `trimws` to trim the additional whitespace prior to merging.

Here is an example based on your (slightly altered) sample data:

```
merge(df1, transform(df2, COUNTYCD = trimws(gsub("\"", "", COUNTYCD))), by = "COUNTYCD")
#  COUNTYCD val_from_df1 val_from_df2
#1    46013   0.33615347    0.9586547
#2    46013   0.46372327    0.9586547
#3    46013   0.06058539    0.9586547
#4    46013   0.19743361    0.9586547
```

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(2018)
df1 <- data.frame(
    COUNTYCD = c("46013", "46013", "46013", "46013"),
    val_from_df1 = runif(4))
df2 <- data.frame(
    COUNTYCD = c(" \"01001\" ", " \"01003\" ", " \"01005\" ", " \"01007\" ", " \"46013\" "),
    val_from_df2 = runif(5))
```

Comment: You’re very welcome @SHILLATE; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for others to identify relevant answer.